# Quick way to find questions nominated for closing?

Tags: support, closed-questions, exact-duplicates, vote-to-close

Is  there a fast way for someone with 3k+ rep to find questions nominated for closing?

If there's not, can we make one?  I think this would prevent a lot of redundant effort, i.e. 5 different highish rep users having to find a duplicate question, or happen to read a question and notice that it has been nominated for closing.

I think we could get a lot more questions closed and cleaned if there were an easy list to check often, and see what other users have nominated for closure.

I apologize if one exists that I don't know about!

**EDIT:**

Removed the part that Sathya (correctly) objected to.

Comment: *for this would be a tag that the nominating user puts on a question, which would allow easy scanning* Disagree with this. Tags are meant to describe in short what the question is about, not what needs to be done.

Comment: @Sathya - I agree!  This is just a  thought, but do you agree that this would be helpful in keeping dupes and such cleaned up?

Comment: @Sathya - it's removed.

Comment: @JNK - It may assist, but disagree that tags are ought to be used like that.

Comment: @JNK. Using tags for that purpose will force us to ban them, and further action if required.

Comment: @Diago and @Sathya - please note I removed that portion of the post :)  Deep breaths, everyone!

Comment: @JNK Please note. Duel notifications in comments **don't work**. One at a time.

Comment: @JNK I know you had removed them, just wanted to let you know my thoughts on the same :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a page available once you reach 10K.

Before then, no, and past request for this has been declined. The page for seeing proposed closed questions is one of the features you can unlock by gaining reputation.

So in short. Keep giving good input and gaining reputation, and you will score :)